# How to record delete events in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to record the delete events in my Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script (delete a cell or entire row) and get the cell number and user name.

Function `onEdit(e)` triggers when cells are edited and not when deleted.

```
function onEdit(e)
{

var range = e.range;
Logger.log(range.getRow());
Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  if (range.getRow() === 3.0) 
  {
    var recipient = "user@example.com";
    var subject = 'Roster Notification';
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "Hello, your roster has been updated. Please check. Thanks."); 
  }
}
```

Comment: `onEdit` does trigger on cell deletion(see duplicate). But not on `REMOVE_ROW`, in which case `onChange`+ `getActiveRange()` can be used.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926676/gas-on-edit-trigger-not-running-when-edited-from-api

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**
Issue#2 linked below is fixed and you can use `getActiveRange()` to retrieve the correct row.

---

Good news & Bad news, I'm afraid.

You can use an [installable Change trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) to get notified about row deletions. (The full list of changes is EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, **REMOVE_ROW**, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT, or OTHER).

The bad news is that the event does not tell you **what changed**, so if you wish to track changes to a roster, you'll need to do that by keeping track of changes yourself.

Related issues from Google's issue tracker:

- [SpreadSheet onChange() trigger event parameter should be more useful](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2751)
- [Spreadsheet onChange() getActiveRange() always yields to A1](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3269) **[FIXED]**
- [INSERT_ROW Undo is not changeType REMOVE_ROW](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5573)

Comment: Issue#2 marked as fixed and `getActiveRange()` does return the correct row.