# Script to run on delete row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I need to run a script to delete a Google Calendar event on deleting a row from Google Spreadsheets.
Do you have any way of getting the data from the row which was deleted?
I have this code to create a Calendar event when a row is changed, but it does not work when it is deleted.

```
function SaveToCalendar(e) {
    const eventCal = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById(CALENDAR_ID);
    const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    const row = e.source.getActiveRange().getRow();
    const cell = e.source.getActiveRange();
    const name = sheet.getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    const eventName = sheet.getRange(row, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
    const description = sheet.getRange(row, 4, 1, 1).getValue();
    const startDate = sheet.getRange(row, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
    const endDate = sheet.getRange(row, 6, 1, 1).getValue();
    const department = sheet.getRange(row, 7, 1, 1).getValue();
    const eventTitle = `${eventName} | ${department}`;
    if(cell.getValue() == APROVADO) {    
        eventCal.createEvent(eventTitle, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate), {
            description: description
        });
    } else {
        var events = eventCal.getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate))
        var foundEvent = events?.find(e => e.getTitle() === eventTitle);
        foundEvent?.deleteEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be able to use onChange() changeType="REMOVE_ROW"

Comment: I added a trigger to On change event. The mentioned script runs based on the trigger. Look at the trigger configuration on the following image.
https://ctrl.vi/i/2aP7wZKkL

Comment: @Cooper, do you know how to take the data from the excluded row?

Comment: I have no idea.  I hardly ever use onChange.

Comment: You can probably determine which one was deleted and get most of the information from the calendar by figuring out which was is in the calendar and not in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script has simple and installable triggers. The change installable trigger for Google Sheets is triggered when changes are done to an spreadsheet including deleting a row. Triggers call a function and send to that funcion an event object. In the case of the change trigger the relevant related event object property is `changeType`. It is helpful for this case because when a row be deleted the values of this property will be `REMOVE_ROW`.

Unfortunately this trigger doesn't include a property with data about the context, so the trigger by itself will not provide the details about what row was deleted.

It looks that the best way to handle this, is by comparing the data in the spreadsheet with data stored in another place, i.e. your script might compare the events data in the spreadsheet with the events in the Google Calendar.

If you are open to change a bit your idea, instead of using a trigger activated by the row deletion you might use a script to do the row deletion and the calendar event deletion.

Related

- [How to record delete events in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38072370/1595451)
- [How to determine the amount of rows inserted in a sheet with onChange trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55406054/1595451)
- [Google Sheets script to insert a timestamp on a row inserted from a form? How to detect the inserted row using onChange?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63839264/1595451)

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/trigges/events